# Talking about things that didn't turn out as you wished

Tags: future-in-the-past

If I want to talk about something that didn't turn out as I wished, should I say:

> I thought that in my new place **I would achieve** anything I wanted in no time.

or

> I thought that in my new place **I would have achieved** anything I wanted in no time.

Why? What's the difference between the two?

Many thanks for your help!

Ethel

Answer (score 0):

When you're addressing hypothetical situations, **would have** usually implies that you're talking about the past, where **would** can be used to talk about the past, present or the future.

Let's take them in reverse order:

> I thought that in my new place I would have achieved anything I wanted in no time.

This is about the past. They expectation that you would have achieved anything you wanted is over (and it doesn't look like you did).

> I thought that in my new place I would achieve anything I wanted in no time.

It's not really clear whether this is about the past, the present or the future. Additional sentences would add the context needed to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

Your second sentence deals with an achieving that may have happened **before you arrived** in your new place Your first deals with an achieving that happens (or doesn’t, but either way) **during your presence** in your new place.